# Use tcl twapi getting "Could not get ITypeInfo for coclass: object does not support IProvideClassInfo and clsid not specified." error ( office365)

Tags: outlook, com, office365, tcl

I am using tcl8.5 and twapi 4.2a1 to control outlook via component object module
as following code

This Code can use in office 2016 outlook but in office365 outlook
I got error "`Could not get ITypeInfo for coclass: object does not support IProvideClassInfo and clsid not specified`" in "`set biid [$::items -bind eventhandler]`"

Could someone give me a idea to solve this problem?

or Am I missing something ?

```tcl
package require twapi_com

proc eventhandler {args} {
    global ns
    set event  [lindex $args 0]
    set handle [lindex $args 1]
    puts $event
    puts $handle
    set s ""
    set sdr2 ""
    #return $s
}

set outlook [::twapi::objcom Outlook.Application -active]
set ns [$outlook GetNamespace "MAPI"]
set contacts [$ns GetDefaultFolder 6]
set ::items [$contacts Items]
set biid [$::items -bind eventhandler]
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems your windows registry keys are corrupted. I'd suggest repairing your Office installation.

Also, you may try to automate Outlook from another programming language to make sure the issue is not related to TCL.

See [HRESULT:0x80040154 COM object with CLSID {} is either not valid or not registered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1999239/hresult0x80040154-com-object-with-clsid-is-either-not-valid-or-not-registere) for more information about the issue.